# python lists append

Tags: python, list, math

I was about to code a program which evaluates a polynomial. But the code below is just a try-out for that. The code below gives an output that stops when "counter = t"... I want it to give an output up to when counter=0. How can that be? I wanted to treat every number(input) as a coefficient of the polynomial. If I was successful doing this, I'm planning to make a list then for every, say, element  in the list, I will then multiply it to a certain number raised to its index then add them up so that I've evaluated a polynomial.. Am I clear? And will my plan work out?? Thank you so much.. Please help..

```
t = input("Enter degree of Polynomial: ")  
while t < 0:  
    print ("Not possible! ")  
    t = input("Enter degree of Polynomial: ")   

counter = 0  

while counter < t:  
    x = input("n: ")

    if x <= 0:
        print "Not possible!"
    else:
        print x**t  
    t-=1  

    counter += 1
```

THe ouput goes like this:
Enter degree of polynomial: 5
n: 5
3125
n:4
256
n:3
27
then it ends.. it should continue asking for an input n up to five times..

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, perhaps you could give an example of what the output of the function *should* be if it worked?

Comment: You need a `continue` after the second `print "Not possible!"`

Comment: @mikeDeSimone It doesn't work out.

Comment: THe ouput goes like this:

Enter degree of polynomial: 5
n: 5  
3125
n:4
256
n:3
27

then it ends.. it should continue asking for an input n up to five times..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Well done - it's only a little mistake: Remove the "syntactic whitespace" in your last line, or remove it completly

Secondly: Don't forget to add the values ;-) - and with regards to your headline, this is best done with a python list.

Comment: Thank you. So will my plan work out?

by the way, the original problem doesn't let us use exponentiation or the ** operator.. How can I do this?? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use raw_input() and keep in mind that raw_input() returns always a string. So you have to convert the returned string to an integer like:

```
>>> x = int(raw_input("foo: "))
```

Then it is possible to test something like x > 2 etc. Without casting to integers the following would happen:

```
>>> "2" > 1
True
>>> "2" > 3
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
while True:
    degree = int(raw_input("Enter degree of Polynomial: "))
    if degree >= 0:
        break
    print ("Not possible!")  

x = float(raw_input("x = "))

y = 0.0
for exponent in reversed(range(degree)):
    k = float(raw_input("k[{0}] = ".format(exponent)))
    y += k * (x ** exponent)

print("y = ", y)
```

This solves a polynomial of the form:

```
y = (k[N-1] * (x ^ N-1) + (k[N-2] * (x ^ N-2) + ... + k[0]
```

Comment: name 'reverse' is not defined :(

Comment: It's `reversed` not `reverse`; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems (to me) that you are having the loop depend on 2 variables, where you perhaps expected it to be only dependent on 1.

Perhaps this works a little better:

```
while t > 0:  
    x = input("n: ")

    if x <= 0:
        print "Not possible!"
    else:
        print x**t  
    t-=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! that's exactly the output I'm expecting !!